# Java и кодировка в консоли windows

Tags: windows, кодировка, java, консоль

Код в `java` получает текст из файла, и сравнивает его с другим текстом. При запуске в `eclipse` все работает, и если тексты совпадают, то выводится сообщение. После экспорта в `jar` файл, приложение работает некорректно в консоли `windows`.
Кодировка проектов и файлов - `UTF-8`.

Comment: [тут все написано][1]

p.s. научитесь пользоваться гуглом. говорят помогает.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143998/cyrillic-in-windows-consolejava-system-out-println

Comment: Там про сравнение 2 строк нет ничего.

Comment: сравнить две строки можно так 

String s1 = "Строка";
if (s1.equals("Строка")) {
            System.out.println("ок");
}

Comment: Я в курсе как сравниваются строки. При запуске в еклипсе они сравниваются и равны, в консоле windows все иначе.

Comment: так вы пример посмотрите ссылку на который я вам указал в ответе. меняйте кодировку консоли и будет вам праздник.

Comment: Я поменял кодировку в консоле с помощью команды chcp 65001. В итоге кодировка изменилась, но условие сравнения срок не выполняется.

Comment: с кодировками сюда: http://skipy.ru/technics/encodings.html
ну и кщё много чего полезного ;)

Answer (score 2):

Проблема эта возникает из-за того, что по-умолчанию кодировка Windows - windows-1251, а в консоли Windows используется кодировка Cp866.  Запускаем консоль, щелкаем на заголовке окна и выбираем свойства. В свойствах на закладке Шрифт ставим шрифт Lucida Console и жмем ОК. Далее набираем в консоли ChCp 1251, в ответ получаем Текущая кодовая страница: 1251. Теперь запускаем Java программу и убеждаемся, что все работает.